# Cygnus to CKAN - Runtime error

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

I'm stuck trying to configure `cygnus` inside an `Orion` running `FIWARE Lab` instance. I'd like the entity data log being stored on `CKAN`.

The first question that comes to my mind is: Will I be able to accomplish this task using `FIWARE Lab`'s own `CKAN` or will I have to install and configure my own?

If this is possible, what should I specify on the `cygnusagent.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host` property? Shall I write down `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` in there?.

I tried using my own API key (the one shown on the field `API Key` at the Data tab) and also that previously mentioned host (`cosmos.lab.fiware.org`) but whenever I subscribe the context I get the following log `cygnus` message:

```
ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process:178)  - Runtime error (Don't know how to treat the response code. Possibly the organization already exists in a deleted state (respCode=404, orgName=cated))
```

I've done several tests such as not specifying the ´Fiware-Service´ but sadly the results always lead to that same error. The 'organization' concept is different from the Data tab (`CKAN`) and the oneshown at `FIWARE Lab` Account tab, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to answer all the questions:

- The Global Instance of CKAN is running at `data.lab.fiware.org`. `cosmos.lab.fiware.org` is the head node of the Big Data Global Instance based on Hadoop.
- The Global Instance of CKAN cannot be used by regular users of FIWARE for publishing private data, it is only intended for reading open datasets. If you have an (already created and stored somewhere else) open dataset you can publish it by contacting the instance administrators.
- Thus, you will have to deploy your own instance of CKAN in order to persist the Orion context data.
- Regarding the way the notified context data maps the CKAN data structure is:

  - A CKAN organization is created based on the notified `fiware-service`. If no `fiware-service` is notified, then the configured `default_service` value is used; this is configured in the Cygnus source.
  - A CKAN package (also know as dataset) is created based on the notified `fiware-servicePath`. If no `fiware-servicePath` is notified, then the configured `default_service_path` value is used; this is configured in the Cygnus source.
  - A CKAN resource is created based on the notified `entityId` and `entityType` (these values are concatenated). A datastore related to this resource is created as well, which is a PostgreSQL table.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This makes me wonder if there isn't any possibility of adding datasets to `CKAN` using `orion` or API applying the same method shown [here](https://www.fiware.org/devguides/publishing-open-data-in-fiware/how-to-offer-datasets-including-context-information-through-the-wstore/offering-datasets-directly-through-the-ckan-interface/) using the interface.

Comment: That's the purpose of Cygnus :) Orion has not the necessary logic por creating organizations, packages, resources etc nor "appending" data to already existent datastores and so on. All this stuff is a work for Cygnus. Of course, you can add to CKAN datastores that you ALREADY have created and stored somewhere else, in a let's say "batch mode". Nevertheless, iteratively creating the dataset based on Orion's data, that's something to definitely do through Cygnus.